# Browsers Suggestion for Testing Website

Tags: html

How could we select `ie7, ie6`options in ie8 browser .
Could anyone suggest me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, you can install the IE Tab Chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

* does **not** support IE 6

Also, take a look at the Microsoft Expression Web SuperPreview:

http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  Anytime I've had to test cross browsers I needed to setup a machine with the specific browser I'm looking to test with.  Usually done using a Virtual Machine environment.  I found this site this morning that allows you to test sites using all the browser versions.  IE is a little more difficult to setup but it does allow for it.  http://www.spoon.net/

Another option to test using IE is downloading the IE collection.  That will install all versions on your machine.  I've found it to work best on XP.

Comment: No, we had an option to choose ie6 and ie7 and we can test our code in all three versions at a time, but i need the correct option where it could be?

Comment: what do you mean an option to choose ie6 and 7?  In the browser's compatibility mode?  That's not a true cross browser test.  Your options would be set in tools -> options.  What option specifically are you looking for?

Comment: Ya I got it, It was in Developer tools, we have an option for IE7 too.

Comment: @user1067018 - Depending on your options being set I wouldn't rely on that as valid cross browser testing.  You really should use the true browser to do the testing.

Comment: http://eabyas.in/FinishingSchool, username : vsmith, password : Vsmith123$ and click on MyCourses and click on Practical C and open the first chapter, Here I have given float left in my styles, even though it is not working and where as in Mozilla, IE8 and Google Chrome are working fine. Could you help me with what went wrong

Comment: @user1067018 please post a new question or add the code your using in this question.  I'd be happy to help but would like to see your css / html code.

Answer (score 0):

For IE 6 and below, I recommend MultipleIE which can be found at http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE.

Other browsers from way back up to the present can be found at http://browsers.evolt.org/, though for running multiple IEs from 7 upwards you'll need a virtual machine (see https://www.virtualbox.org/ for this)